# ¿Como se puede incrementar fechas en una shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

#### Descripción:

Necesito tomar una fecha en formato **dd/mm/yyyy** e incrementar el día.

Por ejemplo, teniendo una fecha `01/01/2017`, la idea es tener la siguiente salida:

```
02/01/2017
```

#### Código:

Estoy intentando con `date -d "${fecha_ultimo_proceso} + 1 day" "+%d/%m/%y"`, pero me está tomando el formato de fecha en inglés (**mm/dd/yyyy**)

La prueba que estoy haciendo es:

```
#/bin/bash

fecha_ultimo_proceso="01/05/2017"

date -d "${fecha_ultimo_proceso} + 1 day" "+%d/%m/%y"
```

y la salida que tengo es:

```
06/01/17
```

#### Nota:

¿Quizás tenga que hacer alguna configuración en mi SO? Estoy usando Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Es difícil entender cuál es la duda. Entras un formato MM/DD/YYYY y te devuelve DD/MM/YYYY porque es así como se lo pides con `"+%d/%m/%y"`. Simplemente gira %d y %m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba este código:

```
date +%d/%m/%Y -d "$DATE + $i day"
```

Comment: Hola @Mariano, siento no poder extenderme más en la explicación. Este código lo tenía guardado para hacer cosas parecidas y lo copié de una página hace mucho, no sé muy bien cómo funciona porque ya no me acuerdo. En el manpage de date seguro que viene explicado, sólo que a mí se me da fatal el inglés. Espero que le sirviera al o.p